# jquery page flickers in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have used jquery for date picker.

Before selecting the date the page scrolls smoothly, but if I select the date in datepicker.

the page starts flickering while scrolling.

```
$("#datepickerTo").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
});

$("#datepickerFrom").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
});


<table class="StandardTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8">SEARCH CALL DETAILS</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>From Number</th>
            <th>To Number</th>
            <th>Mode</th>
            <th>From Date</th>
            <th>To Date</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="fromNumber"
                class="textboxCallHistory" placeholder="From Number" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="toNumber"
                class="textboxCallHistory" placeholder="To Number" /></td>
            <td><select path="country" class="selectBoxMode">
                    <option value="A">ALL</option>
                    <option value="I">IN-COMING</option>
                    <option value="O">OUT-GOING</option>
                    <option value="M">MISSED</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><input id="datepickerFrom" type="text" name="fromDate"
                class="textboxCallHistory" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" /></td>
            <td><input  id="datepickerTo" type="text" name="toDate" class="textboxCallHistory"
                placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="startTime"
                class="textboxCallHistory" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="endTime"
                class="textboxCallHistory" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="search"
                value="Search" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

what could be the problem.

Please help me.